# how to change the add button to a remove button in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have an 'add' button which executes an ajax function, I want to change it to a 'remove' button when it's done executing, I tried making the following:

```
@php
$exists = false;
$user = auth()->user();
if(isset($user->favourites)){
    foreach($user->favourites as $fav =>$value){
        if($value == $title['id']){
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
@endphp
@if($exists == false)
<a href="#" name="fav" onclick="addtofav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Add to Favorites</a>
@endif
@if($exists == true)
<a href="#" name="fav" onclick="removefromfav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Remove from Favorites</a>
@endif
```

and I told ajax to refresh this div on success, everything is fine but it's taking a bit  too long to change and there must be a better way, any ideas??

Comment: I assume your `addtofav()` and `removefromvav()` `onclick` handlers are performing the `ajax` request? I suspect the delay is due to the request being processed and responded to by the server. What you could do is simply disable the button until you get a response from the server, then based on the `success/fail` of that response, either toggle the button to `remove` on success or display an error message on failure.

Comment: You must do it with javascript since it is a client side, you handle the requests via one function and depending on the function you hide or show either the buttons.

Comment: @Peppermintology yes the onclick functions are performing ajax requests, what exactly do you mean by disable?

Comment: @OmarMalas When the request is made, set the [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute on the `button` until you receive a response. This prevents the `button` from being clicked again and provides the user with some feedback that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @elseif to change anything if something is same as the value you set. Try to change this

```
@if($exists == false)
     <a href="#" name="fav" onclick="addtofav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Add to Favorites</a>
@endif
@if($exists == true)
     <a href="#" name="fav" onclick="removefromfav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Remove from Favorites</a>
@endif
```

Into this :

```
@if($exists == false)
     <a href="#" name="fav" onclick="addtofav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Add to Favorites</a>
@elseif ($exists == true)
     <a href="#" name="fav" onclick="removefromfav()" class="parent-btn"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Remove from Favorites</a>
@endif
```